# How to realize a code conversion from nested DVIs to table including class to style?

Tags: php, preg-replace, domdocument, preg-replace-callback

Here's the situation:
I want to change nested DIV elements to table elements, I want the classes to be set as inline style.

I now have an example array with the classes and the style attributes:

```
$classes    = array(
            'container' => 'width: 100%;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;',
            'card' => 'position: relative;display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex;-ms-flex-direction: column;flex-direction: column;min-width: 0;word-wrap: break-word;background-color: #fff;background-clip: border-box;border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);border-radius: 0.25rem;',
        );
```

This code is then to be converted into the following:

```
<div class="container">
    01
    <div class="card">
        02
    </div>
</div>
```

This code is then to be created from this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="container" style="width: 100%;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;">
            01
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="card" style="position: relative;display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex;-ms-flex-direction: column;flex-direction: column;min-width: 0;word-wrap: break-word;background-color: #fff;background-clip: border-box;border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);border-radius: 0.25rem;">
                        02
                    </td>                
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could do something like this? 
I've been experimenting with preg_replace_callback and DOMDocument since Friday. Unfortunately everything without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing particular. All you have to take care is:

- to replace the nodes in reverse order
- to use a deep copy of children nodes (using `DOMNode::cloneNode` with the parameter set to `true`)

I assume you are working with parts of html (not a full document with `<html>` and `<body>` tags), but if it isn't the case you can easily change the code yourself:

```
$cssClasses = [
    'container' => 'width: 100%;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;',
    'card' => 'position: relative;display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex;-ms-flex-direction: column;flex-direction: column;min-width: 0;word-wrap: break-word;background-color: #fff;background-clip: border-box;border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);border-radius: 0.25rem;'
];

$html = <<<'EOD'
<div class="container">
    01
    <div class="card">
        02
    </div>
</div>
EOD;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$divNL = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

for ($i = $divNL->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $node = $divNL->item($i);

    $table = $dom->createElement('table');
    $tr = $dom->createElement('tr');
    $td = $dom->createElement('td');
    $table->appendChild($tr);
    $tr->appendChild($td);

    foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
        $td->appendChild($attr);
    }

    $styles = array_reduce(
        preg_split('~\s+~u', $td->getAttribute('class')),
        function($c, $i) use ($cssClasses) {
            return isset($cssClasses[$i]) ? $cssClasses[$i] . $c : $c;
        },
        $td->getAttribute('style')
    );

    if ( !empty($styles) )
        $td->setAttribute('style', $styles);


    foreach ($node->childNodes as $childNode) {
        $td->appendChild($childNode->cloneNode(true));
    }

    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($table, $node);
}

$result = '';

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $result .= $dom->saveHTML($childNode);
}

echo $result;
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/sAWll)

Comment: That works and for the beginning a good basis for my project.
Thank you very much!